# Ускоряется Setinterval

Tags: javascript

Есть слайдер с переключением слайда через определенный промежуток времени. Сделал так чтобы при клике на кнопку перелистывания слайда таймер, обнулялся и счет начинался с 0. Проблема в том, что при каждом нажатии на кнопку слайдер ускоряется. Вот код.

```
var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".sales-slaider");
var arrowLeft = document.querySelector(".arrow-left");
var arrowRight = document.querySelector(".arrow-right");
var current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Init slider
function initSlide() {
  myTimer = setInterval(function () {
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
      current = -1;
    }
    slideRight();
  }, 4000);
}

function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
  initSlide();
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  initSlide();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
  initSlide();
});

startSlide();
```

Comment: Проблема решена. arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
  initSlide(); Пропустил celarInterval(myTimer)

Comment: если проблема решена самостоятельно, возможно стоит удалить вопрос, т.к. вряд ли он принесет кому-нибудь пользу. Или можно опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Оставил, возможно кому нибудь пригодится

Comment: Спасибо за совет, опубликую ответ)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена.

```
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () { 
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) { 
      current = -1;  
  } 
  slideRight(); 
  initSlide();
```

Пропустил `celarInterval(myTimer)` между  `slideRight();` и  `initSlide();`